# Rails 6 ActiveStorage Attach file url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have an application where a user can upload a PDF document, when the pdf document is uploaded (with a front-end Stimulus controller using ActiveStorage DirectUpload), I then process the PDF to strip content out to place into an Excel Spreadsheet. Everything is uploaded to an s3 bucket.

My model looks like this:

```
class Export < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :pdf
  has_one_attached :spreadsheet

  validates :pdf, attached: true, content_type: 'application/pdf'

  def process_pdf!
    self.pdf.open(tmpdir: "#{Rails.root}/tmp") do |file|
      tmpfile = File.open(file.path)
      file_name = File.basename(file.path).sub(".pdf", "")
      op = PdfScraper.call(pdf_file: tmpfile, output_name: file_name)
      attach_spreadsheet(file_name: file_name)
    end
  end

  private

  def attach_spreadsheet(file_name:)
    self.spreadsheet.attach(
      io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{file_name}.xlsx"),
      filename: "#{file_name}.xlsx",
      identify: false,
      content_type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    )
  end
end
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class ExportsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @export = Export.new(export_params)
    @export.uuid = cookies[:visitor_uuid]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @export.save
        @export.process_pdf!
        flash[:notice] = "Success!"
        format.html { redirect_to download_path }
      else
        flash[:error] = @export.errors
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def export_params
    params.require(:export).permit(:pdf)
  end
end
```

When the redirect happens back to the `download_path`, I am finding the Export based on the cookie ID but when I attempt to inspect (or view) the download URL for the attached spreadsheet, I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass
```

The View looks like:

```
<p>
  <%= polymorphic_url(@export.spreadsheet) %>
</p>
```

I even tried the `rails_blob_url(@export.spreadsheet)` and it doesn't work. If I look up the URL via the rails console, it seems to work.

Comment: Try `@export.spreadsheet.service_url`. That should give you the s3 url.

Comment: @AFOC The content is empty...

Comment: Then apparently it isn't actually attached to whatever `@export` is in your view. I think your question needs more information. How do you define `@export` for your view? What do you enter into the console to look up the URL? What is the stack trace of the error you posted?

Comment: Blah! I'm so dumb... I was looking up the wrong Export model. Figured it out!

Comment: @AFOC Saved me there. I didn't even doubt that the record's been created, since `instance.image` (if the model has `has_one_attached :image`) gave me "something" in a polymorphic way? But I inspected the code after I saw your comment, and it was "of course the record's not created".